# node.js how do I apply XSS Filter at once in actionHero.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use actionHero.js for API Design.
I want to apply XSS Filter at once.

how do I apply XSS Filter ?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are asking "How do I restrict API access to only a fixed domain".

"XSS" or "Cross Site Security" is really only a browser-facing concept, and only has to do with the security of the page.... IE: Disallowing a page on `www.site.com` to use JS or Ajax hitting `www.shady.com`.

Since Actionhero is a server framework, there aren't many parts of ActionHero which focus on the browser.  You do have access to headers which will be returned to all web requests, which include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, the main XSS header for the browser.  You can set it in `./config/servers/web` via the `api.config.servers.web.headers` hash.  Most modern browsers will obey the list of allowed domains.  That said, if you are attempting to block "shady" people (perhaps not even using a browser) from accessing your API, this won't help you at all.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Can you elaborate on the question?